# Retrieving IMEI in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, imei

I need IMEI for validation in a React Native app. Using react-native-device-info library is not an option.

I have tried using [this library](https://github.com/SimenCodes/react-native-imei) but it says `@overide error` when i `run-android`. Also the library is deprecated.

for additional information of my experiment
i tried using [react-native-imei](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-imei)
and this is what happen

[image]

help me please

Comment: Why is using react-native-device-info library is not an option?

Comment: @barry i do use react-native-device-info but this lib have no options of showing device IMEI which is nonsense, and when i try to add the option my self it dont work, even react native-device-info cant give me my macaddress or is it working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[react-native-imei](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-imei) works but you will have to delete @override on line 25 in the IMEI.java in node_modules/react-native-imei/android/src/main/java/codes/simen/IMEI

re run-android and i think it will work

Comment: `undefined is not an object`, It breaks!

Comment: @NishantGhodke Did you got another way?

Comment: @Rohit Parte- did you find any solution ?