# How to access the IMEI in react-native

Tags: react-native, imei

I searched alot and tried some ways but none of them worked. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70377596/get-imei-number-in-react-native), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47196866/retrieving-imei-in-react-native), ...

I want to get IMEI in react-native , so I installed [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-imei) and call it as below:

```
import IMEI react-native-imei
IMEI.getImei().then(imeiList => {
    console.log(imeiList); // prints ["AABBBBBBCCCCCCD"]
});
```

But when I want to get IMEI, get the following error ?

> getImeiForSlot: the user 10265 does not need the requirement to access
> device identifiers.

How can I achieve this feature?

any help would be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

IMEI access is forbidden as it is a persistent hardware identifier and those are no longer exposed (for android Q and higher). Although if you want to access it, you should add permission to your manifest file [Doc](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#non-resettable-device-ids) and ask for permission before fetching it. If you don't know how to do it, let me know to provide you a sample code.